# What is the maximum amount of bins possible in an OpenCV histogram?

Tags: c++, image, video, opencv

What is the maximum amounts of bins I can use in an histogram (the size of the histogram). I am using a histogram for the h and s plane of hsv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the number of values you want to count (normally 8-bits, but could be more). So, for 8-bits you would need a maximum of 256 (2^8) bins to count every possible 8-bit value.

Here is an example with [calcHist](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/histograms.html?highlight=calchist#cv2.calcHist) that actually uses HSV data.